# Where to put functions that don't map to state?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, redux

React/Redux n00b here :) - working with a crappy API that doesn't correctly return error codes (returns 200 even when end point is down), therefore is messing up my Ajax calls. Owner of the API will not able to correct this soon enough, so I have to work around it for now.

I'm currently checking each `success` with something like this (using lodash):

```
success: function(data) {
    // check if error is REALLY an error
    if (_.isUndefined(data.error) || _.isNull(data.error)) {
        if (data.id) data.sessionId = data.id;
            if (data.alias) data.alias = data.alias;
              resolve(data || {});
    } else {
        reject(data); // this is an error
    }
 }
```

I want to move this into it's own function so that I can use it with any action that performs an Ajax call, but I'm not sure where to include this.

Should this type of function map to state (hence, treat it like an action and build a reducer) or should this be something generic outside of Redux and throw in `main.js` for example?

Answer (score 2):

You can dispatch different actions depending on if the promise was resolved or not. The simplest way would be something like this:

```
function onSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_THING_SUCCESS",
    thing: data
  };
}

function onError(error) {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_THING_ERROR",
    error: error
  };
}

function fetchThing(dispatch, id) {
  // the ajax call that returns the promise
  fetcher(id)
    .then(function(data){
      dispatch(onSuccess(data));
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      dispatch(onError(error));
    });
}
```

Heres some more [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) how to do this kind of thing...